# Rank all the elements in a matrix with respect to their row and column

Tags: python, matrix

Suppose I have a matrix (2d list in Python) and I want to create another matrix with the rank of all the elements based on the row and column they are in. The conditions are:

1. Rank should start from 1
2. Same rank should be provided for same elements in the same row or column
3. Same elements may have different ranks if they are in different rows or columns based on their particular row or column ranking
4. The maximum rank should be as small as possible

Suppose the 5X5 matrix given is:

```
18, 25, 7, 11, 11
33, 37, 14, 22, 25
29, 29, 11, 14, 11
25, 25, 14, 14, 11
29, 25, 14, 11, 7
```

The expected output is:

```
3, 4, 1, 2, 2
6, 7, 3, 4, 5
5, 5, 2, 3, 2
4, 4, 3, 3, 2
5, 4, 3, 2, 1
```

How can I write this code in Python or any programming Language or what is the algorithm behind solving this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taking inspiration from Faruk Hossain's answer. You can start by creating tuple.

1. Create a tuple with (value, row_number, col_number) for each element and store them in a list.
2. Sort the tuple in ascending order by the value
3. Iterate based on values now for each tuple, find maximum ranked element in it rows an d columns from elements that are already ranked (i.e. elements with value<=current value), now fix the value of current element as maximum of these two numbers and add a plus 1 if maximum is not equal to current element.
4. Also note that here we need to do an additional step if maximum of row and column both happen to have value equal to value of current element, we need to recursively update the rank of elements equal.

To signify importance of 4th step take matrix

3 2 4
5 1 3
2 6 4

Here if we first fill bottom 4 then if we will rank it as 3 but next when we rank top row 4 as 4 we will have a contradiction.

Time complexity - **O(n^4)**

Answer (score 2):

Try using this nested list comprehension:

```
print([[sorted(set(i)).index(x) + 1 for x in i] for i in l])
```

Output:

```
[[3, 4, 1, 2, 2], [4, 5, 1, 2, 3], [3, 3, 1, 2, 1], [3, 3, 2, 2, 1], [5, 4, 3, 2, 1]]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with different ways.
I am providing a simple way to do this.

Steps:

1. Create a tuple with (value, row_number, col_number) for each element and store them in a list.
2. Sort the tuple in ascending order by the value
3. Iterate through the list. At each iteration you will get a `tuple`. For each `tuple` now you have `row` and `column` number of that value. And we will rank this position `(row, col)`. Iterate to current `row`, `column` and find the **maximum** value has at that row and column. Now current position's rank will be **maximum** between that specific `row and column` + **1** (Or **0** at some cases). *You can maintain two arrays to optimise this searching*.
4. Follow the previous steps until we finish the task for all elements.

I was asked this question at a Software Engineering interview.